# How to retrieve an array of images from a plist file which is displayed in an imageview?

Tags: objective-c

I have taken the plist file in that take array of images... In that pass, there are five images, but how do I retrieve these images in our view?

My code is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Animalfile" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray *animalImages=[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSMutableArray *animal=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(int i=0;i<[animalImages count];i++)
    {
        UIImage *img=[animalImages objectAtIndex:i];
        [animalphoto setImage:img];
        NSLog(@"print:%@",i);

        //NSString *name=[animalImages objectAtIndex:i];
        [animal addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",img]]];
    }
}
```